# How can the exit status of a process depend on whether it's statically built?

Tags: c, gcc, static-linking, dynamic-linking, libc

A modern system:

```
% pacman -Q glibc gcc
glibc 2.16.0-4
gcc 4.7.1-6
% uname -sr
Linux 3.5.4-1-ARCH
```

A trivial program:

```
% < wtf.c   
void main(){}
```

Let's do static and dynamic builds:

```
% gcc -o wtfs wtf.c -static                               
% gcc -o wtfd wtf.c
```

Everything looks fine:

```
% file wtf?                                             
wtfd: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0x4b421af13d6b3ccb6213b8580e4a7b072b6c7c3e, not stripped
wtfs: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0x1f2a9beebc0025026b89a06525eec5623315c267, not stripped
```

Could anybody explain this to me?

```
% for n in $(seq 1 10); do ./wtfd; echo $?; done | xargs
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
% for n in $(seq 1 10); do ./wtfs; echo $?; done | xargs
128 240 48 128 128 32 64 224 160 48
```

Sure, one can use `int main()`. And `-Wmain` will issue a warning (`return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’`).

I'd just like to understand what is going on there.

Comment: The return value of `main` should `int`, as per the specification.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'm not saying this is good code. I'm not asking how to fix it. I'm asking how the behaviour can actually vary depending on how I link.

Comment: Read the answers again. Especially the parts about registers. Then look at the disensammbled code to see what _actually_ happens, and you will most likely see that there is a difference.

Comment: There's about 139138 lines in `objdump -S`. I would have hoped there was a simpler explanation.

Answer (score 6):

That's EXACTLY the point.

There is no "void main()". There is ALWAYS a result value, and if you don't return one and don't do anything in your program, the return value is what happens to be in the appropiate register at program start (or specifically, whatever happens to be there when main is called from the startup code). Which can certainly depend on what the program is doing before main, such as dealing with shared libs.

EDIT: to get an idea how this can happen, try this:

```
int foo(void)
{
    return 55;
}

void main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

There is no guarantee, of course, but there's a good chance that this program will have an exit code of 55, simply because that's the last value returned by some function. Just imagine that call happened before main.

Comment: You're not tackling the part that surprises me: how static versus dynamic makes any difference. Once the dynamic loader is done, I expect the `_start` entry point to be called. I cannot think of anything that'd make it different between static and dynamic builds of `glibc`.

Answer (score 2):

To further illustrate what Christian is saying. Even though you declared `void main()` your process will return whatever value was previous in `eax` (since you are on linux x86 arch).

```
void main() {
    asm("movl $55, %eax");
}
```

So now it always returns 55 b/c the above code explicitly initializes `eax`.

```
$ cc rval.c 
$ ./a.out 
$ echo $?
55
```

Again this example will only work on the current major OSs since I am assuming the calling convention. There is no reason an OS could not have a different calling convention and the return value could be somewhere else (RAM, register, whatever).